# How to make the button bold based on it's state? e.g(If the button is selected it should be bold.)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This is my html file. How do I get to make the selected/active button bold.

```
   <md-menu md-position-mode="target-right target">
        <stx-action-view-options ng-click="ctrl.viewOptMenu($mdMenu, $event)" desc="View options"></stx-action-view-options>  
        <md-menu-content style="max-height: none;">
            <md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="" >Default</md-button></md-menu-item> but
            <md-menu-item ><md-button ng-click="">Documentation</md-button></md-menu-item>
            <md-menu-item ><md-button ng-click="">WIP</md-button></md-menu-item>
            <md-menu-item ><md-button ng-click="">Activated Node</md-button></md-menu-item>
        </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
```

This is my .js file

```
    this.viewOptMenu = function($mdMenu, $event){
            $mdMenu.open($event);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Which selection button you want bold declare class name in html.

```
<md-button>Class="btn1"</md-button> //declare in html button tag
```

Then,
In .css file use the class and do whatever you want.
For active keyword is using for when you click the button it will work.

```
.btn1:active

font-weight:500;///change button color anything.
```

Comment: could it be done like this, for example  

        ng-style="{ 'width' : toDisplayDetails ? '1000px' : '0' }"